# Prevent browser scrolling to :target

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

How can I make it so the browser doesn't scroll down to the element which matches the :target (the #comment in the URL)?

Example

```
#toTarget {
 Color: red;
}
#toTarget:target {
 Color: green;
}
```

I don't want it to scroll on div#toTarget.

It can be any language... javascript, css, html, etc...

Comment: That's a function of the browser. CSS *certainly* can't do anything about it, and I'm not sure if JavaScript can prevent it.

Comment: according to definition of E:target selector "an E element being the target of the referring URI" so if you have a name="comment" id="toTarget" it most definitely will scroll down and light green, but not focus, how did it gain focus in your case?

Answer (score 1):

By not using a fragment identifier such as `#toTarget` at the end of a URL. It is not a comment but *defined* to specify a particular location in a document, so browsers do a natural thing when they position the document accordingly in the window. Reference: STD 66, clause 3.5 [Fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5).

Comment: Then, i can do an div whit "top: 0; position: absolute;" than whit the :target selector modify another div?

Comment: @Marcos, is there something wrong with my answer? Regarding your new question, I cannot figure out what you are asking. Perhaps you should start with a new question and explain what you are doing and include some code that illustrates it, and describe what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, i saw it wrong. I can do for example: "#worker:target .toModify { ... }?